# how do I change default MTU from 1500 to 9000 for lxdbr0 for containers created using LXD?

Tags: 14.04, networking, lxc, lxd, container

I'm running linux containers created by LXD on ubuntu 14.04.05 . I have a lxdbr0 interface setup , but its default MTU is 1500 , how do I update it ? I tried the following command, but it doesnt work.

```
sudo ifconfig lxdbr0 mtu 9000
SIOCSIFMTU: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your command is correct. The error you're seeing indicates that the interface (hardware) isn't Gigabit or doesn't support JumboFrames.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/jumbo_frames

Answer (score 0):

See question: https://serverfault.com/questions/845337/how-do-i-change-default-mtu-for-lxdbr0-for-containers-created-using-lxd

Answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1013269/138644

```
lxc network set lxdbr0 bridge.mtu=1234
```

Answer (score -1):

Check "sudo brctl show lxdbr0". If there are other interfaces which are part of this bridge then those interfaces MTUs need to be changed to this value.

Looks like MAX bridge MTU is minimum MAX of all underlying interfaces and will be allowed a change only when those allow it.