# Sun Java install download hangs.. how to diagnose this?

Tags: networking, java, vmware

I'm looking for suggestions on how to troubleshoot this.

I am running VMWare 6.5 on a Supermicro blade server about 2000 miles away, with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS installed as a VM.

I know that the datacenter server is able to download at a speed of at least 200 megabit/sec.

I am trying to install Oracle Java 8. During the install, the download pauses for a long time.

```
@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  java-common oracle-java8-set-default
Suggested packages:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic | ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho | ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming firefox | firefox-2 | iceweasel | mozilla-firefox | iceape-browser
  | mozilla-browser | epiphany-gecko | epiphany-webkit | epiphany-browser | galeon | midbrowser | moblin-web-browser | xulrunner | xulrunner-1.9 | konqueror | chromium-browser | midori | google-chrome
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  java-common oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/47.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 174 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package java-common.
(Reading database ... 93941 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../java-common_0.56ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking java-common (0.56ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java8-installer.
Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java8-installer_8u144-1~webupd8~0_all.deb ...
Unpacking oracle-java8-installer (8u144-1~webupd8~0) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up java-common (0.56ubuntu2) ...
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u144-1~webupd8~0) ...
No /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc file found.
Creating /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc and
using default oracle-java8-installer wgetrc settings for it.
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2017-09-02 13:12:40--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.219.92.226, 23.219.92.200
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.219.92.226|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-09-02 13:12:42--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 104.107.16.233, 2600:1400:a:296::2d3e, 2600:1400:a:289::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|104.107.16.233|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1504376084_bce6b70ee84b122d9c91bbce6738203e [following]
--2017-09-02 13:12:44--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1504376084_bce6b70ee84b122d9c91bbce6738203e
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.219.92.226|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 185515842 (177M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz’

     0K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........  1% 4.12M 42s
  3072K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........  3% 8.64M 31s
  6144K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........  5% 6.31M 29s
  9216K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........  6% 9.12M 26s
 12288K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........  8% 7.08M 25s
 15360K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 10% 8.99M 23s
 18432K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 11% 7.33M 23s
 21504K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 13% 7.33M 22s
 24576K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 15% 6.01M 22s
 27648K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 16% 6.16M 22s
 30720K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 18% 7.03M 21s
 33792K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 20% 7.44M 21s
 36864K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 22% 6.11M 20s
 39936K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 23% 6.16M 20s
 43008K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 25% 6.12M 20s
 46080K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 27% 6.04M 19s
 49152K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 28% 5.88M 19s
 52224K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 30% 7.29M 19s
 55296K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 32% 6.03M 18s
 58368K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 33% 5.64M 18s
 61440K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 35% 5.44M 18s
 64512K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 37% 6.08M 17s
 67584K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 39% 6.06M 17s
 70656K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 40% 7.52M 16s
 73728K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 42% 6.13M 16s
 76800K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 44% 6.14M 15s
 79872K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 45% 5.09M 15s
 82944K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 47% 7.34M 14s
 86016K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 49% 7.36M 14s
 89088K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 50% 6.06M 14s
 92160K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 52% 7.26M 13s
 95232K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 54% 5.29M 13s
 98304K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 55% 8.94M 12s
101376K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 57% 4.61M 12s
104448K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 59% 6.09M 11s
107520K ........ ........ ........ .
```

.

And there it will sit, but it won't fail. It does ultimately succeed:

.

```
2017-09-02 13:28:01 (6.38 MB/s) - Read error at byte 111798454/185515842 (Success). Retrying.

--2017-09-02 13:28:02--  (try: 2)  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1504376084_bce6b70ee84b122d9c91bbce6738203e
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.219.92.226|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 185515842 (177M), 73717388 (70M) remaining [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz’

        [ skipping 107520K ]
107520K ,,,,,,,, ,,,,,,,, ,,,,,,,, ,....... ........ ........ 61% 5.32M 28s
110592K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 62% 6.23M 16s
113664K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 64% 7.13M 13s
116736K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 66% 7.10M 11s
119808K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 67% 6.74M 10s
122880K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 69% 6.25M 9s
125952K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 71% 7.29M 8s
129024K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 72% 6.25M 8s
132096K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 74% 6.28M 7s
135168K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 76% 6.08M 7s
138240K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 78% 8.18M 6s
141312K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 79% 9.79M 6s
144384K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 81% 8.99M 5s
147456K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 83% 5.31M 5s
150528K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 84% 8.37M 4s
153600K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 86% 5.47M 4s
156672K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 88% 7.28M 3s
159744K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 89% 6.87M 3s
162816K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 91% 7.59M 2s
165888K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 93% 6.14M 2s
168960K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 94% 8.77M 1s
172032K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 96% 6.21M 1s
175104K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 98% 6.10M 0s
178176K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ......  100% 6.03M=11s

2017-09-02 13:28:13 (6.58 MB/s) - ‘jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz’ saved [185515842/185515842]

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jexec to provide /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/appletviewer to provide /usr/bin/appletviewer (appletviewer) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/extcheck to provide /usr/bin/extcheck (extcheck) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/idlj to provide /usr/bin/idlj (idlj) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jar to provide /usr/bin/jar (jar) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jarsigner to provide /usr/bin/jarsigner (jarsigner) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (javac) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javadoc to provide /usr/bin/javadoc (javadoc) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javafxpackager to provide /usr/bin/javafxpackager (javafxpackager) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javah to provide /usr/bin/javah (javah) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javap to provide /usr/bin/javap (javap) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javapackager to provide /usr/bin/javapackager (javapackager) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jcmd to provide /usr/bin/jcmd (jcmd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jconsole to provide /usr/bin/jconsole (jconsole) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jdb to provide /usr/bin/jdb (jdb) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jdeps to provide /usr/bin/jdeps (jdeps) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jhat to provide /usr/bin/jhat (jhat) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jinfo to provide /usr/bin/jinfo (jinfo) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jmap to provide /usr/bin/jmap (jmap) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jmc to provide /usr/bin/jmc (jmc) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jps to provide /usr/bin/jps (jps) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jrunscript to provide /usr/bin/jrunscript (jrunscript) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jsadebugd to provide /usr/bin/jsadebugd (jsadebugd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jstack to provide /usr/bin/jstack (jstack) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jstat to provide /usr/bin/jstat (jstat) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jstatd to provide /usr/bin/jstatd (jstatd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jvisualvm to provide /usr/bin/jvisualvm (jvisualvm) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/native2ascii to provide /usr/bin/native2ascii (native2ascii) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/rmic to provide /usr/bin/rmic (rmic) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/schemagen to provide /usr/bin/schemagen (schemagen) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/serialver to provide /usr/bin/serialver (serialver) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/wsgen to provide /usr/bin/wsgen (wsgen) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/wsimport to provide /usr/bin/wsimport (wsimport) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/xjc to provide /usr/bin/xjc (xjc) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so to provide /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so (mozilla-javaplugin.so) in auto mode
Oracle JDK 8 installed

#####Important########
To set Oracle JDK8 as default, install the "oracle-java8-set-default" package.
E.g.: sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
On Ubuntu systems, oracle-java8-set-default is most probably installed
automatically with this package.
######################

Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java8-set-default.
(Reading database ... 93989 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java8-set-default_8u144-1~webupd8~0_all.deb ...
Unpacking oracle-java8-set-default (8u144-1~webupd8~0) ...
Setting up oracle-java8-set-default (8u144-1~webupd8~0) ...
```

While it is stuck, I can still open another SSH to the box, and do stuff, works fine, etc. Top:

```
top - 13:23:35 up 19 days,  7:06,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 214 total,   1 running, 213 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 57719684 total, 46507260 free,   429944 used, 10782480 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 56646644 avail Mem
```

Everything else I do with this system seems to be working fine. I did a remote copy of about 100 gigabytes via SFTP to this virtual machine, and that did not hang like this.

Is there some way to see what is going on with the ubuntu hardware or network, when it hangs like this? Would I need to do a packet capture to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue and resolved it by changing the MTU. try changing it to something like 1451 or less.

[how do I change default MTU from 1500 to 9000 for lxdbr0 for containers created using LXD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906706/how-do-i-change-default-mtu-from-1500-to-9000-for-lxdbr0-for-containers-created)